# does'nt join the room || Photon Pun

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am recently working on my multiplayer game Using Unity3d and Photon PUN2;

I want to make a system where player clicks the button to *join the room* if it is not avilabe *then create*;

When staringt the game from two players (parrelSync) from **p1** it just make a room normal (because in starting no rooms are available)

form **p2** it does not join the room

***here is the code***

```
        string roomID = "002";
        string maxPlayers = "10";
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = (byte)int.Parse(maxPlayers);
        if(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom != null){
            PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(roomID);
        }else{
            PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomID, roomOptions);
        }
    }
```

[image: here is what i logged form p1]

[image: here is what i logged from p2]

Comment: `PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom` is the room you are currently in ... this will **always** be null at this moment ...

Comment: yes you'r right but if it is null it should create a room as written but its not even doing that.

Comment: Please also use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is clearly in `c#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom` returns the room which you are currently in, which will always be null in your case.

Instead of checking for `PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom` just use `PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom` and also override the `OnJoinRoomFailed()` which will be called when we attempt to join the room with `roomID` which does not exist yet, and in it just create new room.

Something like following would work

```
private string roomID = "002";

private void YourMethod() {
    string maxPlayers = "10";
    RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
    roomOptions.MaxPlayers = (byte) int.Parse(maxPlayers);

    PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(roomID);
}

public override void OnJoinRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message) {
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomID);
}
```

And to override `OnJoinRoomFailed()` make sure your script is derived from `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks` class